# Default IIS 7 Logon Domain

Tags: iis, iis-7, dns, basic-authentication

I need to change the default logon domain on our website, but for some reason it still puts the computer domain as the default at login. I tried the following: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) but get the same results. what else could it be?

I can't seem to find any other solutions on the web, any ideas? I compared the IIS configuration to another server (that works) and it looks identical. can't for the life of me figure out what's going on.

Comment: If you follow that Microsoft article, your server side setting is correct. If problem remains, that means the web browser does not behave correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you authenticate to a website there are many points at which one can be presented with a login dialog. I'm going to assume you have a simple website made of only basic .HTM .CSS and .JS files. (Meaning, you aren't using ASP.NET and looking to have forms based authentication.)

The website itself, runs under the domain/user configured on the Application Pool the website runs under. I suspect you are NOT trying to adjust this. It is the security level under which the entire website's process runs. Meaning, without an end user logging in at all, this is what the website's security level is in regards to accessing the file system, network, registry, etc.

If you want ONLY users in one of your network's Windows domains to have access, you should go to the IIS website, click 'Authentication' and disable Anonymous, ASP.NET Impersonation and Forms Authentication. Then set just the domain in basic authentication to what you need it to be.

If this is what you've done, and it still fails. Then I suspect it's because the IIS machine probably needs to meet some requirement to allow this to happen. For example: It needs to be added as a member of the domain you are trying to configure. Another possibility is that some setting on the domain controller, or an inability to reach it, is preventing the webserver from presenting your web visitors with the option to log on to that domain.